# Is there a way to know that admob ads are ready or not

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I am using Unity to create games. Admob integration is easy with unity. Now you know there is a function in unity of

```
ad.IsReady()
```

I make a button interactable when ad loads by using it and uninteractable if it's not yet loaded. Now
is there any function in admob too just like this unity function. Thanks for any of your help

Answer (score 1):

**When the ad loaded:**

```
public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
}
```

**When the loading failed:**

```
public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: "
                        + args.Message);
}
```

And you can find everything you want [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial)